# How do I use a delimiter with Scanner.useDelimiter in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

```
sc = new Scanner(new File(dataFile));
sc.useDelimiter(",|\r\n");
```

I don't understand how delimiter works, can someone explain this in layman terms?

Comment: here, this is how it works: http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/usedelimiter-string-pattern-method-example/

Comment: @ema--I assume that was tongue-in-cheek because it's only clear if you already "understand how delimiter works" and NoMoreErrors does NOT. E.g., what a "delimiter pattern" is might just un-clear what you've said, which surely isn't wrong, just not helpful to the Q. But at least you didn't insult NoMoreErrors like so many do, with glee, I imagine.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> The scanner can also use delimiters other than whitespace.

Easy example from [**Scanner API**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
 String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";

 // \\s* means 0 or more repetitions of any whitespace character 
 // fish is the pattern to find
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");

 System.out.println(s.nextInt());   // prints: 1
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());   // prints: 2
 System.out.println(s.next());      // prints: red
 System.out.println(s.next());      // prints: blue

 // don't forget to close the scanner!!
 s.close();
```

The point is to understand the regular expressions ([`regex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) inside the [**`Scanner::useDelimiter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)). Find an `useDelimiter` tutorial [**here**](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/usedelimiter-string-pattern-method-example/).

---

To start with regular expressions [**here you can find**](http://regexone.com/) a nice tutorial.

## Notes

```
abc…    Letters
123…    Digits
\d      Any Digit
\D      Any Non-digit character
.       Any Character
\.      Period
[abc]   Only a, b, or c
[^abc]  Not a, b, nor c
[a-z]   Characters a to z
[0-9]   Numbers 0 to 9
\w      Any Alphanumeric character
\W      Any Non-alphanumeric character
{m}     m Repetitions
{m,n}   m to n Repetitions
*       Zero or more repetitions
+       One or more repetitions
?       Optional character
\s      Any Whitespace
\S      Any Non-whitespace character
^…$     Starts and ends
(…)     Capture Group
(a(bc)) Capture Sub-group
(.*)    Capture all
(ab|cd) Matches ab or cd
```

Comment: just fyi: this line: Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*"); actually   has a resource leak, even if you call s.close(). The leak is on the scanner that useDelimiter is called on. If you instead call 
    `Scanner s = new Scanner(input);  
    s.useDelimiter(\\s*fish\\s);`
you avoid this problem.

Comment: @georges actually my line is: ("\\s*fish\\s*")... not ("\\sfish\\s") but can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: In other words, to a novice this Answer and comments is no help whatsoever to NoMoreErrors. Learn `regex` just to use `Scanner`?????? Sure, it would help, but it's waaaaaaay past what he needs. Just give an example. Simple friggin' example.

Comment: @DSlomer64 actuallty you don't need `regex` to use `Scanner` but if you want to use your custom delimiter is mandatory to use `regex` because is what `useDelimiter` method accepts as input. This is what OP asked and as long as is the accepted as answer, IMHO it suits OP. Why you think OP is a novice? If being a novice it's your case and the answer does not fit you please ask a new question `:)`

Comment: @JordiCastilla--OP is almost definitely a novice because of the level of his question and rep 353. So his `useDelimiter` example certainly needs explaining, My point was that we need to factor in user's experience and actual need and not go off on a tangent (from user's point of view) but you've made me realize this: the user can quit reading comments once he's in too deep or continue reading to learn more.I was reading too much from OP's mind. Your point is well taken. **:^}**

Answer (score 12):

With Scanner the default delimiters are the whitespace characters.

But Scanner can define where a token **starts** and **ends** based on **a set of delimiter**, wich could be specified in two ways:

1. Using the Scanner method: [**useDelimiter(String pattern)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String))
2. Using the Scanner method : [**useDelimiter(Pattern pattern)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) where Pattern is a regular expression that specifies the delimiter set.

So `useDelimiter()` methods are used to tokenize the Scanner input, and behave like [StringTokenizer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), take a look at these tutorials for further information:

- [**Setting Delimiters for Scanner**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SettingDelimitersforScanner.htm)
- [**Java.util.Scanner.useDelimiter() Method**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_usedelimiter_string.htm)

And here is an [Example](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/usedelimiter-string-pattern-method-example/):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Initialize Scanner object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("Anna Mills/Female/18");
    // initialize the string delimiter
    scan.useDelimiter("/");
    // Printing the tokenized Strings
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }
    // closing the scanner stream
    scan.close();
}
```

Prints this output:

```
Anna Mills
Female
18
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
String myInput = null;
Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
System.out.println("Enter your input: ");
myInput = myscan.next();
System.out.println(myInput);
```

This will let you use Enter as a delimiter.

Thus, if you input:

```
Hello world (ENTER)
```

it will print 'Hello World'.

Comment: Yeah, but how does it work? What are TWO backslashes for? But hooray, now we know how to use Enter as a delimiter. Assuming it works.