# how to get substring between two delimeters in java

Tags: java, string, split, substring, delimiter

I want to get substring from starting line third comma(delimeter) and from ending line second comma(delimeter).
eg:-
input:
"8884052344,89,\N,11805143\,3\,6112555\,6538937\,5839176\,5420860\,6590106\,2646753,0,2015-09-29 10:52:29"

Output:
11805143\,3\,6112555\,6538937\,5839176\,5420860\,6590106\,2646753
Note: From the starting line third comma and from ending line second comma substring may increase the size.Please help me.

Thanks.....

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Are you expecting us to write the code for you? Try some code and then if you have a problem, come back and ask it here.

Comment: I tried using indexOf() and substring() methods.

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the string by the "," and than make a new string, read this [How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Will the String always have more than 5 commas ? I have assumed that it will , We can solve it in two ways.

**First approach**

I have used **indexOf** to determine the index of third occurrence of "," and **lastIndexOf** to determine the second last occurrence of ",".

```
String ex= "8884052344,89,jhgN,11805143,3,6112555,6538937,5839176,5420860,6590106,2646753,0,2015-09-29 10:52:29";
int beginningIndex= ex.indexOf(',',(ex.indexOf(',',ex.indexOf(',')))+1)+1;
int lastIndex= ex.lastIndexOf(',',ex.lastIndexOf(',')-1);
String desiredResult=ex.substring(beginningIndex,lastIndex);
```

**Other approach** .

you can just split the String , you will get an array . create a StringBuffer and append the String from the index 3 till the second last index ( array length - 3 ) .