# Java - Using Delimiter not removing special character

Tags: java

The text file contains the following data. I wish to remove the '$' from each row of the text file. I also wish to store the Name,Drink and Cost in variables for future manipulation. However, that can be performed later. I do not understand what is wrong with my code,  Here is the 
Textfile Data:

Problem solved using Regex escape pattern. I had to replace the "$" with "\s*\$\s*"

```
Rubin$Vodka$55
Alex$Gin$22
Max$Water$FREE
```

Code:

```
  File filename = new File("animals2.txt");        
        try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(filename);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner linesc = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("$");

        while(linesc.hasNext()){
            String name = linesc.next();
            txaDisplay.append(name + "\n");

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Comment: I do not understand why my code does not work

Comment: You had your answer but the idea is to read how useDelimeter work. This is well explain in the duplicated question. The parameter is a regex, `$` is a special character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change this line of code:

```
 Scanner linesc = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s*\\$\\s*");
```

You need to pass a regular expression pattern escaping the $ sign.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved with regex escape pattern!

Comment: Slight problem, it only prints the first line

Comment: Because you only loop on the first line of the first Scanner you used...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
File filename = new File("animals2.txt");        
    try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(filename);

    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        StringBuffer txaDisplay = new StringBuffer();
         String line = sc.nextLine();
         StringTokenizer linesc = new StringTokenizer(line,"/($)/g");

         while(linesc.hasMoreElements()){
            String name = linesc.nextToken();
            txaDisplay.append(name+" ");
         }
         System.out.println(txaDisplay);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` method of the `String`. You cannot accomplish what you are trying with Scanner.

```
public static void main( String[] args)
{
    File filename = new File( "animals2.txt");

    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( filename);

        while( sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] arr = line.split( "\\$");

            for( String str : arr)
            {
                txaDisplay.append( str + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As a side note, do not use [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Here is what the documentation says:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: This will not work if you have a line like this : "$$" if you need to keep the same number of lines per original lines.

Comment: Nothing in the original post indicates that $$ is a valid input line.

Comment: Clarification of my above comment, it does not remove the $ sign

Comment: Well, nothing tell you it is an invalid input line

Comment: @AxelH well, the sample input does.

Comment: I give you that since this will work better with this regex ;)

Comment: It works but it only prints a single line (well a single line from the textile, i.e Rubin/nVodka/n55

Comment: It might be related to how txaDisplay.append works, it works as intended when I use System.out.print( str + "\n");

Comment: Okay fixed it, how can i store each type in a variable for manipulation. (name/drink/price etc)?

Comment: I just removed the for loop and created variables storing the drink at[0] name at[1] and price at [3]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        try {
        File file = new File("animals2.txt");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for(String s: lines)
        {
            String str[] = s.split("$");
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            {
                 txaDisplay.append(str[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use Guava's [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

```
File filename = new File("animals2.txt");
final Splitter dollarSplitter = Splitter.on('$'); // checks for the char, not the regex.
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(filename)) {
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  for (String name: dollarSplitter.split(line)) {
    txaDisplay.append(name + "\n");
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you need to do to loop correctly on each line using the delimiter correctly: (based on your code)

```
Scanner sc = null, scLine = null;
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(new File("./test.txt")); //CHANGE THE FILE HERE

        String s;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            scLine = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
            scLine.useDelimiter("\\$");
            while(scLine.hasNext()){
                s = scLine.next();
                System.out.println(">" + s); //HERE YOU NEED TO APPEND INTO YOUR INSTANCE
            }
            System.out.println("#"); //AND REMOVE THIS LINE. I WORKED IN CONSOLE TO TEST THIS
            scLine.close();
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(scLine != null) scLine.close();
        if(sc != null) sc.close();
    }
```

The first loop is design to read EVERY line of the file.
For each line, you use a Scanner that will use the regex to split the line based on the `$` sign.

This could be done with the `String.split("")` methods but I kept your design here. (Split use a regex but remove empty cell on the beginning and on the end).

And of course, you need to close every scanner correctly. So during the loops and in the finally in case of an exception.

Answer (score -2):

```
String[] parts = line.split("$");
String name = parts[0];
String alcohol = parts[1];
String price = parts[2];
```

Comment: @AxelH of cause. you need to think about corner cases yourself

Comment: Well, nothing warns him that the split methods trim the empty cells (except the doc)... so he might be stuck a long time before he understand that. And since you did not explain anything... well this is not a good answer.