# Java Delimiter Issue

Tags: java, delimiter

I am having trouble with delimiters.  My code is as follows:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\\D");
int x,y,z;
System.out.println("Enter 3 digits:  ");
x=in.nextInt();
y=in.nextInt();
z=in.nextInt();
System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
in.close();
```

Pardon my lack of experience with delimiters, but I can only get my program to separate input with 1 character, not two.  The program must be able to take input as follows:

either `1 2 3` or `1, 2, 3`.
currently it can handle `1 2 3` and `1,2,3` but not `1, 2, 3`

The extra spaces in the last case must be throwing it off.  How do you handle this?

Additionally, I must be able to take in a variable number of integers as input, up to 100 integers, and insert them into a queue.  Obviously the three variables I have defined are not enough but clearly defining 100 would also be overkill.  What is the most efficient way to handle this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the delimiter? `nextInt` should read the whole number correctly

Comment: 1. use arraylist to store the values 2. Take a look at this answer for more clarification on delimiters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28766480/2235972

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the Delimiter to `\\D+` (i.e. `in.useDelimiter("\\D+");`).

**EDIT:**
At the moment, you are asking the delimiter to split on a single non-digit character. By adding the + you are telling it to split on continuous blocks of non-digit characters. The delimiter is a regular expression, and there's more information on those here: [www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: At the moment, you are asking the delimiter to split on a single non-digit character. By adding the `+` you are telling it to split on continuous blocks of non-digit characters. The delimiter is a regular expression, and there's more information on those here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you.  Much better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\\D+");
int n=5; // Here you should define your limit
int[] data=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter "+i+" digit:  ");
    data[i]=in.nextInt();
}

// print store value
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(data[i]);
}
in.close();
```

Above code helps you to get n no. of integer inputs