# Scanner line separator not working with intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner

this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Insert number:");
    int read = creaScanner().nextInt();
    System.out.println("I read "+read);
}

private static Scanner creaScanner() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    return s;
}
```

When i run it and type an int and hit enter it just takes me to the next line and displays nothing. 
Without the line

```
s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

everything works just fine, but this code worked on Eclipse, so i wanted to know if i have to change some settings to make it work on Intellij.

Thanks you in advance

PS

My question is different from this one ( [How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner) ) because i already know how to use scanner and this code runs correctly in Eclipse, but not in intellij. So i was wondering if there's some settings to change to make it work also on intellij. (I am not allowed to change that part of the code, so the answer i am looking for is probably about an intellij setting).

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess ... you're using the builtin consoles for both IDEs, right? They probably just handle enter/newlines differently.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you know if i can fix this by changing some settings? (because i am not allowed to change that part of the code)

Comment: try it in console.