# Can I make it so I don't have to add a space to get the sum?

Tags: java

first time posting here and I'd like some help , I started learning java some days ago and I tried to make a very simple calculator. Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            double input1, input2;

            System.out.println("Type your calculation below");

            input1 = input.nextDouble();
            String operator = input.next();
            input2 = input.nextDouble();

            switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println(input1 + input2);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(input1 - input2);
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println(input1 * input2);
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println(input1 / input2);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

When I run this I have to type a number press space and then type the other number like this : 15 + 15. Can I somehow make it so that I don't have to press space every time? So I can type it like this : 15+15.

Also if you have any tips or if you see any mistakes I'd be happy to hear your opinion.

Comment: you can try to use delimiter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner

Comment: You know you can press enter after each input right? this is also a way to use scanner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) for `Scanner` see below:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(foo);
s.useDelimiter(" ");

// do input stuff here
```

Comment: `Scanner` has already split input by whitespaces, so there is no necessity to `useDelimeter(" ")`