# Java String Split with multiple delimiter using pipe '|'

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to break a string b = "x+yi" into a two integers x and y.

This is my original answer.
Here I removed trailing 'i' character with substring method:

```
int Integerpart = (int)(new Integer(b.split("\\+")[0]));
int Imaginary = (int)(new Integer((b.split("\\+")[1]).
                      substring(0, b.split("\\+")[1].length() - 1)));
```

But I found that the code below just works same:

```
int x = (int)(new Integer(a.split("\\+|i")[0]));
int y = (int)(new Integer(a.split("\\+|i")[1]));
```

Is there something special with '|'? I looked up documentation and many other questions but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: In a regular expression, `'|'` means _or_

Comment: How or works with String? Split function takes parameter String but ("a" | "b" ) doesn't look like a String for me.

Comment: The split method interprets the string you pass to it as a regular expression. See [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I looked over that part. Thank you

Comment: I edited the question sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the given link for understanding of **How Delimiters Works**.

[How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

**Another alternative Way**

You can use useDelimiter(String pattern) method of Scanner class. The use of useDelimiter(String pattern) method of Scanner class. Basically we have used the String  semicolon(;) to tokenize the String declared on the constructor of Scanner object.

There are three possible token on the String “Anne Mills/Female/18″ which is name,gender and age. The scanner class is used to split the String and output the tokens in the console.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * This is a java example source code that shows how to use useDelimiter(String pattern)
 * method of Scanner class. We use the string ; as delimiter
 * to use in tokenizing a String input declared in Scanner constructor
 */

public class ScannerUseDelimiterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize Scanner object
        Scanner scan = new Scanner("Anna Mills/Female/18");
        // initialize the string delimiter
        scan.useDelimiter("/");
        // Printing the delimiter used
        System.out.println("The delimiter use is "+scan.delimiter());
        // Printing the tokenized Strings
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
        // closing the scanner stream
        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The split() method takes a regular expression that controls the split. Try
"[+i]". The braces mark a group of characters, in this case "+" and "i".

However, that won't accomplish what you are trying to do. You will end up with something "b = x", "y", "". Regular expressions also offer search and capture capabilities. Look at String.matches(String regex).