# Java scanner multiple/several delimiter conditions

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, conditional-statements, delimiter

I have a problem in finding the right way to only get city1, city 2 and the distance without the "km", using a scanner and delimiter. I need to get the text in bold.
String (example):

**city1**, country; **city2**, country; **145** km

My Delimitar so far because I really have no idea:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(";");
```

I also tried using string.split("") without success.

Should I first devide it in 3 parts on the ";" and do a new delimitar for each part? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance

(Edit to explain difference to another post:
I tried it with regex, with also no luck. I need to split the string on multiple places on different characters. I wouldn't ask a question if I'm able to solve it with another post.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Comment: @tima, no not really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Scanner` and `String#split`:

```
String source = "city1, country; city2, country; 145 km";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
scanner.useDelimiter(";");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // trim() removes leading and trailing whitespace
    String line = scanner.next().trim();
    // split the line on either ',' or a space
    String[] split = line.split(",|\\s");
    // print the first word
    System.out.println(split[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String data = "city1, country; city2, country; 145 km";
String city1Val = data.split(";")[0].split(",")[0];
String city1Con = data.split(";")[0].split(",")[1];
String city2Val = data.split(";")[1].split(",")[0];
String city2Con = data.split(";")[1].split(",")[1];
String distance = data.split(";")[2];
```

Note: If you want distance as number, try as follows,

```
distance = distance.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other answer just fitted better for me. For the distance I already used a substring: distance.substring(0, distance.length()-3).