# Java: how to read with scanner using delimiters "<" or ">" or "><"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Good morning,

I want to read a .txt file using Scanner in this format:

```
Scanner scan = < trains>< intercity>< from>< stationname>
```

Question: how to seperate the tokens such that I will remain with tokens

**trains intercity from stationname**

such that I can use `scan.next()` ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner

Comment: please take a look at `Scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern)`

Comment: In case you're thinking of using Scanner to read an XML file: don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Scanner instance from the String and use a regex for the delimiter.
Following is an example:

```
    String a = "< trains>< intercity>< from>< stationname>";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a);
    scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\<|\\>|\\>\\<"));
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(scanner.next());
    }
    scanner.close();lose();
```

Output:

```
 trains intercity from stationname
```