# How to use more than 2 delimiters

Tags: java, delimiter

I want to delimit `,\\s` but I also want to delimit `\n`, what I thought of so far was `,\\s||\n` but this didn't work, anyone got an idea? It of course worked as a delimiter, but it gave back `IPHONE , 7.0, 4, ., 7, A, false, 0` whilst I want back `IPHONE 7, 4.7, A10, GSM, JET BLACK, 32GB, TRUE, 700`

The file I'm scanning is this:

```
IPHONE 7, 4.7, A10, GSM, JET BLACK, 32GB, TRUE, 700
IPAD AIR 2, 9.7, A8, TRUE, SILVER, 64GB, 400
```

The code I'm using to scan it, is this:

```
public static iPhone read(Scanner sc) {
        boolean touchtech = false;
        //int price = 12;
        sc.next();
        sc.useDelimiter(",\\s||\n");
        String model = sc.next();
        double screensize = sc.nextDouble();
        String processor = sc.next();
        String modem = sc.next();
        String color = sc.next();
        String memory = sc.next();
        String touchtechtest = sc.next();
        if(touchtechtest.equals("TRUE")) {
            touchtech = true;
        }
        int price = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        iPhone res = new iPhone(model, screensize, processor, modem, color, memory, touchtech, price);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide some additional context.

Comment: You could just read one entire line from the scanner, then use `String.split()` to split it into pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes String.class itself is more than enough to handle your needs. Why don't you split the line instead using regex and operate on the result? e.g.

```
public static iPhone read(Scanner sc) { // Better yet just make it received a String
    final String line = sc.nextLine();
    final String [] result = line.split("(,)\\s*");

    // count if the number of inputs are correct
    if (result.length == 8) {
        boolean touchtech = false;
        final String model = result[0];
        final double screensize = Double.parseDouble(result[1]);
        final String processor = result[2];
        final String modem = result[3];
        final String color = result[4];
        final String memory = result[5];
        final String touchtechtest = result[6];
        if(touchtechtest.equals("TRUE")) {
            touchtech = true;
        }
        final int price = Integer.parseInt(result[7]);
        return new iPhone(model, screensize, processor, modem, color, memory, touchtech, price);
    }
    return new iPhone();// empty iphone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useDelimiter` receives a regex. So, in your case, correct string would be `"(,\\s|\n)"`. Your OR conditions go into round parentheses, and are separated by single pipe, not double pipe.

You can also refer to this excellent answer:
[How do I use a delimiter in Java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner)

Comment: I just tried that, it did not work. It gives an InputMismatchException for line 28, which in this case is the line int price = sc.nextInt();

Comment: It has to be the right format. If I change it into a String it works and gives back 700, which is an int right?

Comment: I think the parentheses are unnecessary here.