# Login form while loop not functioning correctly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The loop is working fine except no matter what you put into `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` and I click the *Login* button, I get the message box saying *invalid password try again*. It is not crashing, just saying the password and username are always incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            File loginF = new File("users.txt");

            //userTextField.getText();
            //pwBox.getText();
            //Scanner fileScan = null;

            try {
                Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(loginF);
                fileScan = new Scanner(new File("users.txt"));
                fileScan.useDelimiter(",");

            boolean found = false; 

            while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
                String input = fileScan.nextLine();
                String Username = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
                String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '), input.length());

                if (Username.equals(userTextField) || (Password.equals(pwBox))) {
                    found = true; // added this to set found
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                }

                if (!found) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Invalid password. Try again.",
                        "Error Message",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ProjectLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }  
        }

   });
```

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your error message logic is held within the loop. Try pulling it out of the loop, or rework the logic. Move the below code.

```
             if (!found) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Invalid password. Try again.",
                    "Error Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my aproach

1. check that user AND password match (change OR to AND)
2. stop loop when a match is **found**
3. check if **found** after loop ends

   ```
   try 
   {
       Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(loginF);
       fileScan = new Scanner(new File("users.txt"));
       fileScan.useDelimiter(",");

       boolean found = false; 

       while (!found && fileScan.hasNextLine()) 
       {
           String input = fileScan.nextLine();
           String Username = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
           String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '),   input.length());

           //user AND password have to match 
           found = (Username.equals(userTextField) &&  (Password.equals(pwBox))) ;

       }

       if(found)
       {
           //You should redirect to the lading page..instead of this
           System.out.println("Success!");
       }
       else 
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Invalid password. Try again.",
               "Error Message",
               JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(ProjectLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,    null, ex);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am still having some issues with this code. Now, it is saying there is a match each time no matter what you put into the username and password textfields. I have tried adjusting where I think appropriate but still no success. Any idea how you would go about this? Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkM the userTextField and pwBox are being assigned or modified after they were input ? the file has the correct format ? are you seening any exception ?

Comment: so the file is separated by ", and also has new lines, and between user and password there is a space ? that sounds weird, maybe that is causing your problems

Comment: So the file it is reading from goes exactly like this:                    mark,1234
sean,2345. Each username and password combination are on a new separate line. Is this the problem?

Comment: since user and pass are separated by "," why are you using indexOf(' ') ? try usin fileScan.next() to obtain username and password (since you already configure it to use "," as a field separator)