# Is a Scanner Delimiter of Only a Comma Possible in Java? (for CSV files, no libraries)

Tags: java, csv, delimiter

I specifically want to only use a comma as my delimiter to read a CSV file.

For instance, a program might read a person's name, clock-in, and clock-out times. The associated CSV file might contain:

John Doe, 09:00, 17:00

The program should be able to read three separate tokens:

"John Doe", "09:00", "17:00"

the code I have set up goes something like this:

```
/* main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // scanner object
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

        // set delimiter, read comma and single space as delimiter
        get.useDelimiter(", ");

        // prompt for file
        System.out.println("Provide a file name:");
        File employeeRecords = new File(get.nextLine());
        get = new Scanner(employeeRecords);

        // test run
        // read: employeeName, clockIn, lunchIn, lunchOut, clockOut
        // "Employee" is an object
        Employee $1 = new Employee(get.next(), get.next(), get.next(), get.next(), get.next());

        // .timeWorked is a method of the "Employee" object
        System.out.println("\nEmployee $1: " + $1.name + ", minutes worked: " + $1.timeWorked);
    }
```

However, the problem I get is whenever I provide the csv file, the scanner ignores the delimiter arguments I provided.

The csv file specifically only contains one line:

John, 07:59, 12:00, 12:31, 17:00

The tokens I get from the five `get.next()` statements are:

"John,", "07:59,", "12:00,", "12:31,", "17:00"

which means that the print statement prints out

Employee $1: John,, minutes worked: -1443

Ignoring the obvious bug in minutes worked, is there a way to only use commas as the delimiter?

EDIT:
Not sure how to mark a comment as the answer, or if it is possible, but my bug in question was my delimiter had been defined before redefining the scanner object, as Slaw points out.

Comment: You call `get.useDelimiter(", ")` but then create a **new** `Scanner`. You don't set the delimiter of this new `Scanner` to a non-default value. You should probably just move `get.useDelimiter(", ")` to after `get = new Scanner(employeeRecords)`.

Comment: What if their name is John Doe, Jr.?

Comment: Delete `get.useDelimiter(", ");` and add it to the second assignment: `get = new Scanner(employeeRecords).useDelimiter(", ");`

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-with-scanner-usedelimiter-in-java) is about the `Scanner` and `useDelimiter`. The answer is quite detailed, maybe you want to have a look at it.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah you provided the solution to the specific issue I'm looking to solve. I did in fact redefine the scanner object after adjusting the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- delete the comma manually (as the problem appears to happen at the last character only)
- read in entire lines (call that line `string`) and use `string.split(",")`, instead of using the delimiter in the scanner class itself. This will return a string array containing the line, split by commas.